# Internal microphone not working.. again (Fedora 20, KDE, HP 8460p)

Tags: linux, fedora, audio, alsa, microphone

Unfortunately I have yet another "adventure" with my internal microphone. Everything is un-muted in alsamixer, as well as in pavucontrol. It is not the first time it stopped working, but now - for good.

System:

HP 8460p (Webcam and micro are on one wire and cam is working, so I don't think it is hardware problem. I've tried to use it on Ubuntu (with Unity) and Lubuntu to check if this is not kmixer's or Pulseaudio's fault. No luck so far, but when it happened previously I couldn't get it to work there also.

alsa-info: [alsa-info](http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=b7ad4e070d63a5b52c65bd72629e58df9f03dbde)

Comment: what program are you using to capture the input from microphone?

Comment: I've tried: Skype, pavucontrol (just to check if there is any input, no luck) and built-in alsa tool (arecord or aplay, I do not recall now).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in my HP 2570p and this fixed it for me:

```
$ sudo dnf update
```